# Não apanha id no full calendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Eu tenho um código bem estruturado do `fullcalendar` onde eu consigo fazer tudo menos uma coisa. Quando carrego no `event`, eu queria que ele apagasse e removesse do calendario. Ele apaga da base de dados mas não remove do calendário.

Isto é o código que tenho

```
events: [
                <?php 
                $data = date("yy-mm-dd");
                $select=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from aulas");
                while($mos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
                    $id_cat=$mos['id_categoria'];
                    $sel_cat=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from categorias where id = '$id_cat'");
                    $mos_cat=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel_cat);
                    $titulo=$mos_cat['nome'];
                ?>
                {
                    title: '<?=$titulo; ?>',
                    color: '<?=$mos_cat['cor']; ?>',
                    start: '<?=$mos["data"]; ?>T<?=$mos["inicio"]; ?>',
                    ini_hour: '<?=$mos["inicio"]; ?>',
                    id: '<?=$mos["id"]; ?>',
                    fin_hour: '<?=$mos["fim"]; ?>',
                    end: '<?=$mos["data"]; ?>T<?=$mos["fim"]; ?>',
                },
                <?php } ?>
            ],
```

Como podem ver, eu defino ali o id e tudo é apresentado corretamente.

```
eventClick: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
    swal({
          title: "Deseja apagar este evento?",
          text: event.title,
          type: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
          confirmButtonText: "Apagar",
          cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
          closeOnConfirm: true,
          closeOnCancel: true
        },
        function(isConfirm) {    
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "cod_ajax/apaga_event.php",
                  data: "id="+event.id,
                  cache: false,
                  success:function(e){
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' [ event.id ] )
                    $("#pop").hide(0);
                    $("#pop").fadeIn("fast");
                  }
              })
        });

},
```

Com o código acima, ele apaga da base de dados mas não remove o evento, mesmo referindo `event.id` que penso ser assim que deva por como tem [AQUI](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEvents/) mostrado.

Alguém sabe o que está errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o que tinha errado. O código que tinha escrito apanhava bem o `event.id` mas onde fui buscar o código, tem um erro que é no `.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' [, idOrFilter ] )`. The "," is wrong in there, it needs to be out of "[ ]" and now it's working fine.